# The mystery of fixing a Javascript heap out of memory by calling a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, create-react-app

In a a create-react-app application, I have a test that causes a fatal error because of JavaScript heap is out of memory. I managed to get rid of it, but I'd like to understand why, if not by chance :)

Here is the code snippet where the crash happens :

typescript

```
export function toJsonString(
  model: any,
  options: ToJsonOptions = { shared: true },
  stringifyOptions?: stableStringify.Options
): string {
  return stableStringify(new ToJsonContext().toJson(model, options), stringifyOptions)
}
```

`stableStringify` is an external depedency, and `new ToJsonContext().toJson(model, options)` is some code of my app which is responsible for converting a model into Json.

So I'm experiencing JavaScript heap out of memory with the code above. But strangely enough, if I put the conversion to json behind a function, the crash does not happen anymore :

typescript

```
export function toJson(model: any, options: ToJsonOptions): SerializedJson {
  return new ToJsonContext().toJson(model, options)
}

export function toJsonString(
  model: any,
  options: ToJsonOptions,
  stringifyOptions?: stableStringify.Options
): string {
  return stableStringify(toJson(model, options), stringifyOptions)
}
```

Is there some tricky optimization happening there or am I missing something ?

My tests are run in node with jest, using the out-of-the-box create-react-app scripts.

Edit : the stack trace when the error happens looks like this :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[26672:000001988ED662B0]    39532 ms: Mark-sweep 1302.2 (1339.0) -> 1302.1 (1338.0) MB, 349.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.595, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[26672:000001988ED662B0]    39902 ms: Mark-sweep 1302.1 (1338.0) -> 1302.1 (1338.0) MB, 370.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.408, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000002BDA025C5C1]
Security context: 0x03ddc5b1e6e1 <JSObject>
    1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [00000348261539C9] [native array.js:~87] [pc=000002BDA0B608FD](this=0x0040333826f1 <undefined>,l=0x0064ab89d141 <JSArray[174105]>,m=174105,A=0x0040333828c9 <true>,w=0x03ddc5b5c669 <String[1]: ,>,v=0x0040333829a1 <false>)
    2: Join(aka Join) [0000034826153A19] [native array.js:~112] [pc=000002BDA0B5ADB8](this=0x0040333826f1 <unde...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF69E460EFA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF69E43A296 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF69E43AC80 node_module_register+2160
 4: 00007FF69E6D09BE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF69E6D08EF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF69EC0E954 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+11476
 7: 00007FF69EC0C6E8 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2664
 8: 00007FF69E7AF0CB v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap+59
 9: 00007FF69EAA4E92 v8::intern
```

Comment: In the above one you are creating memory for `object` and it still get referred thus `garbage collector` does not clear it, however when you using it as `fn ` , each time fn execution context get created and destroyed after the use of the object which also clears the `object` inside fn

Comment: @SatyamPathak by `object` your mean the object created by `new ToJsonContext()` ? Did not think it was so big that garbage collecting it would make a big difference, but it would make sense.

Comment: Yes I mean as `object` , I believe the problem is not related how big `object` is instead how many time this particular object get created, which then makes `heap` full of space